# Sitecore User Group - Budapest #4

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**About the event:**

The next Hungarian Sitecore User Group has been announced! There will be two topics:

- Sitecore 9 Fedarated Authentication - László Bényász (@POSSIBLE)
- Sitecore 9 Forms - Tamás Székely (@ALLWIN Informatika)

Free discussions, pizza, drink and beer after the presentations.

**When (UTC):** Thursday, April 5, 2018 6:00 PM

**Where:** POSSIBLE CEE Budapest, Bocskai út 134-146., Budapest

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/248661082/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 2 days